# Hiding unsubscription and View it online links when viewing newsletter online

Tags: php

I have this case. I have a site that is sending newsletters to subscribers. The email template is generated by a PHP template (e.g. single-newsletter.php)

When a user receives this newsletter in his email client, he/she can read the content as well as see these links:

a.) Link to view the newsletter online (This online content is still using single-newsletter.php template).

b.) Link to unsubscribe the newsletter.

Everything is perfect in the email side, so this is working as intended.

My problem is when a user clicks on the "View it online" link, the newsletter (which is now viewed online and not on his/her email client) still has the "view it online" and unsubscription links. I want these two links to be removed. Is there a easy and simple way (without side effects from my existing setup) that this can be remove when a user is viewing the newsletter online?

The email body is generated by doing a file_get_contents to the email template then put it on the $mail_body variable. I am thinking of using this condition in PHP:

```
if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {

//no user agent, this is the file_get_contents reading it
//render the View it online and subscription links
//So it will appear in the email body

} else {

//user agent detected, must be a user reading this online with his browser
//Don't show the view it online and unsubscription links

}
```

Please let me know if this is a good solution, if you have other good solutions. Please share. Thanks.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Why don't you just add `?inBrowser=1` to the "View it online" link in the email.  Then just do `if (!array_key_exists('inBrowser',$_GET)) {echo "<a href=''>link</a>";}` to show the link in the template if it's in an email?

Comment: Cool, let me know if it works, and I'll add this as an answer if get your desired result.